# Como puedo poner una lista en el if __name__ == "__main__":, en lugar de una tupla

Tags: python, lista, tuplas

Intentaré explicar-me lo mejor posible, entonces me salió un problema mientras estaba intentando hacer un código, intente hacer debugging y el error que sale es: **'tuple' object does not support item assignment**.
Sé que las tuplas son inmutables y que su valor no cambia, pero que una lista si, como podréis ver en el código de abajo, está todo en listas menos la "tupla", pongo entre comillas porque no sé si es una tupla o una lista lo que hay en el `if __name__ == "__main__":`:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    func_listt('X','3','4','5','2','6','7','8','9')
```

intente poner-lo así:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    func_listt(['X','3','4','5','2','6','7','8','9'])
```

pero tampoco va bien.

Si alguien sabe alguna solución a este problema(yo pienso que el problema es `func_listt('X','3','4','5','2','6','7','8','9')`, ya que en el código donde pone: `first_position = listt[poscion] = 10` ,me lo marca en rojo y dice: **'listt' does not support item assignment**) se agradecería mucho!!

Aquí os dejo el código por si queréis ver-lo:

```
def  func_listt(*listt):
    new_l = []
    num_num = []
    stike_simb = 'X'
    while range(len(listt)):
        for i in listt:
            if i == stike_simb:
                poscion = listt.index(i)
                if i == 'X':
                    first_position = listt[poscion] = 10
                    next_position = int(listt[poscion+1])
                    next_positionn = int(listt[poscion+2])
                    new_l.append(first_position + next_position + next_positionn)
            else:
                if i != 'X':
                    num_num.append(i)
        break
    print(new_l + num_num)    
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    func_listt('X','3','4','5','2','6','7','8','9')
```

Gracias de Antemano!!

Comment: la verdad no sé bien que querés hacer, pero podrías agregar a la función en la primera sentencia: listt = list(listt)  así no sería una tupla ya que la estás parseando a lista.

Comment: intente poner lo que  me dijiste: def  func_listt(listt = list(listt)):

Comment: también puse el listt = list(listt) fuera de la funcion y el listt dentro como argumento

Comment: incluso intnte     list(func_listt('X','3','4','5','2','6','7','8','9'))